# What is the solution of making dynamic subdomain like links

Tags: magento, subdomain

I have a shopping mall site built with Magento. The url is like http://exampleshopping.com
Now I have requirement where each of my users will have a vanity URL like the following -

```
http://abc.exampleshopping.com
http://xyz.exampleshopping.com
```

In the above example abc, xyz are the user names.

How is this possible without creating a sub domain from the control panel. I need this to be created automatically when a user registers.

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an .htaccess file with the following code to build a dynamic username as subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exampleshopping\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.exampleshopping\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?username=%1 [L]
```

All visits to http://username.exampleshopping.com will redirect to www.exampleshopping.com/userpage.php?username=subdomain. User only see http://username.exampleshopping.com in the address bar.

Reference : http://www.panolee.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your main .htaccess file (for the www subdomain) - or in the Apache Vhost config.

*Replace sonassi.com and paths to suit.*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.sonassi\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.sonassi\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=%1$1 [L]
```

You need to also create a wildcard DNS A record, if you are using cPanel, you would use

```
*.sonassi.com => my.ip.add.ress
```

Or, if you are using TinyDNS - use the following syntax

```
+*.sonassi.com:my.ip.add.ress:86400
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a htaccess regex url Rewrite will work for you.

Comment: Can you please tell me this in details or with example.